# Node Worker Threads and working with TypeORM

Tags: node.js, multithreading, typeorm, worker-thread

I have a NodeJS application running TypeORM to run SQL queries. I have set up worker threads to handle some massive sql queries to avoid freezing the rest of the application while running the queries.

When trying to send the TypeORM connection to the worker thread, I get DataCloneError, meaning I cannot send the connection directly to the worker. Instead, I have to create a new connection for every new worker created, which is an unfortunate and slow solution.

Is there any way I can access the TypeORM connection inside the worker thread?